# How do I set up a NodeJS Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an environment using `npm`. My package.json is as follows:

```
`{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.7",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  }
}`
```

How do I set up a Node.js + Express server practically, so I can be able to spin it up and go to http://localhost:3000, and also take in all my static html/css files, as well as my React jsx files?

Comment: Have you tried the introductory guide on the Express.js website? http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: There are a *ton* of resources online that explain exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way to stand up an express app quickly is to use [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

```
npm install express-generator -g
express --view=jade myapp
cd myapp
npm install
npm start
```

It starts up on port 3000. You can easily change this to 8000

(the above steps are an abbreviated version of the instructions at [expressjs.com](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html))

Alternatively, you can use the this Yeoman [generator](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress) for expressjs. It scaffolds expressjs with interactive documentation, api validation, structured logging, and ES.next. See [generator-express-no-stress](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress).

```
install -g yo generator-express-no-stress
yo express-on-stress myapp
cd myapp
npm run dev
```

Answer (score -3):

In terminal if you have already installed node you can do:

http-server  -p

For example if you have a website in a folder "foo" located in your desktop, you can open a terminal in that folder and do:

http-server . -p 8000

Comment: `http-server` is not a global executable distributed with Node.js (and doesn't appear to be built on Express.js either)

Comment: Probably I misunderstood the question... I thought he simply wanted to test some web content he had already developed. I often do this.

Comment: Whilst http-server is a brilliant utility it has nothing to do with express.

Comment: @al27091 — the question title specifically mentions Express.